# Store text from modal input field in session

Tags: php, session

I'm storing data from mysql in SESSION and passing it to another page where I make zip with all data's and download it. So far everything work just perfect.

Now I'm trying to make when user click on download button before to make actual download to enter name for the zip archive in modal window and then download the archive. So far I've made the modal but now I can't figured it out how to pass the input field text into the session. All other data is passed correctly. Here is the source so far

```
if(! isset($_POST['showcart'])) exit;
echo '<a class="btn btn-danger btn-lg pull-right" style="margin: 10px;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalNorm">Download All Files</a>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed responsive" id="sort">
                    <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Title</th>                  
                    <th>Description</th>               
                    <th>Action</th>
                </tr>
                    </thead>';
foreach ($_SESSION['itemid'] as $i):

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM uploads WHERE upload_id = :id"; 
    $result = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $result->bindParam(":id", $i);
    $result->execute();                 

    $resArray = $result->fetchAll();

     foreach ( $resArray as $row ):?>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="box-content">
                <tbody>
        <tr>    
            <td class="center"><?=$row["upload_id"]?></td>
            <td class="center"><?=$row["upload_title"]?></td>                    
            <td class="center"><?=$row["upload_description"]?></td>
        </tr>
                </tbody>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModalNorm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" 
             aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <!-- Modal Header -->
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" 
                           data-dismiss="modal">
                               <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                               <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
                        </button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">
                            Please enter the name for the archive
                        </h4>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Modal Body -->
                    <div class="modal-body">

                        <form role="form">
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="exampleInputEmail1"></label>
                              <input type="text" class="form-control"
                              id="archiveName" placeholder="Please enter the name for the archive"/>
                          </div>

                        </form>


                    </div>

                    <!-- Modal Footer -->
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"
                                data-dismiss="modal">
                                    Close
                        </button>
                        <a href="create_zip.php" class="btn btn-primary">
                            Download
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>                                       


    <?php endforeach;?>

 <?php endforeach; ?>
 </table> </div>
```

On the `create_zip.php` I take all from `$_SESSION['itemid']` but this `<input type="text" class="form-control" id="archiveName" placeholder="Please enter the name for the archive"/>`

How to take also this input?

Comment: do it either as an AJAX button which calls create_zip.php onClick, passing the archiveName field with it, or you could hook into the click event and pass the value of archiveName as a _GET parameter.

Comment: How can I make it with AJAX `do it either as an AJAX button which calls create_zip.php onClick, passing the archiveName field with it`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this quite easy actually. Firstly wrap your table around `<form></form>`
So it will happen something like this

```
if(! isset($_POST['showcart'])) exit;
echo '<form action="create_zip.php" method="post">
         <a class="btn btn-danger btn-lg pull-right" style="margin: 10px;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalNorm">Download All Files</a>
      <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed responsive" id="sort">
         <thead>
           ....
                    <!-- Modal Body -->
                    <div class="modal-body">

                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="archiveName"></label>
                              <input type="text" class="form-control"
                              id="archiveName" name="archiveName" placeholder="Please enter the name for the archive"/>
                          </div>

                    </div>
                    <!-- Modal Footer -->
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"
                                data-dismiss="modal">
                                    Close

                        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Download" class="btn btn-primary">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>                                       

    <?php endforeach;?>

 <?php endforeach; ?>
</table> </div></form>
```

Then in `create_zip.php` just check if isset submit button and assign variable.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{   
     //your code
     $archiveName = $_POST['archiveName'];

     // other source
} else { echo 'no archive'; }
```